# Excel VBA Sometimes Requires a Delay (Application.Wait or Debug.Print)

Tags: vba, excel

I have noticed this over the years (so it applies to Excel 2007 and long before), and I was hoping someone else has also seen this, and found a cure.

*Sometimes* (maybe once a year) there is a little piece of my code that requires some kind of delay.

*Sometimes* when this Function is called it calculates correctly, but other times not. I have found that when I step through the function, it is *always* correct. Therefore, I tried inserting little delays. These always work, but it seems stupid.

In the snippet below, I can uncomment either of the three stupid lines, with varying levels of success. (You can see that I was thinking that maybe the Now or TimeValue function was a clue.) I can also comment out only the `+ TimeValue("00:00:00")` part and get different results. Right now, it works with the `+ TimeValue("00:00:00")` part commented out. When I started writing this question, I needed the `+ TimeValue("00:00:00")` part!

Has anyone seen this? Is there a cure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I can't give all the code (thousands of lines in over 35 modules, classes, sheets, and forms), but here is a snippet:

```
Private Function Calc_4( _
        s As Long, _
        i As Long _
        ) As Boolean

   Dim l_d_DummyDoubleForWaiting as Double

   On Error GoTo EWE

   With w.cmp(s)

      'This fake delay seems to be required sometimes
      'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:00")
      'Debug.Print Now + TimeValue("00:00:00")
      'l_d_DummyDoubleForWaiting = Now + TimeValue("00:00:00")

      .d_O(i) = _
            O_Given_Dh_and_a( _
                  .d_Dh(i), _
                  .pipe_Suction.fluid_out(i).d_a)

      [Bunch of stuff]

   End With

   Calc_4 = True
   Exit Function
EWE:
   Calc_4 = False
End Function

Private Function O_Given_Dh_and_a( _
      i_d_Dh As Double, _
      i_d_a As Double _
      ) As Double

   If (i_d_a_ft_per_s = 0) Then

      O_Given_Dh_and_a = 0

   Else

      O_Given_Dh_and_a = _
               i_d_Dh _
             / i_d_a ^ 2

   End If

End Function
```